# How do I import Notes from my iPhone to my iPad?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, notes.app

For some reason, I can't import Notes from my iPhone to my iPad via iTunes - is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

Configure your iCloud account in the prefs on both devices to sync notes and they will be done over the air.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the same AppleID, you can set up your iCloud to share your notes between devices.
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12081?locale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

iTunes used to sync them along with Calendars and Reminders several years ago, but it is an option any longer.

Apart from iCloud you can sync notes between iPhone and iPad directly via the Mail, if mail providers support this. Gmail does it for me. They will be stored on mail server in Drafts folder. When adding your email Accounts on iOS devices make sure Notes are toggled.